# Google Analytics : Is tracking status instantaneous?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently trying to setup tracking at my website. I'm trying to determine whether my tracking is actually working.

It says Tracking not detected on the Google Analytics page.

However, when I go to the Realtime reporting, it actually says 1 visitor detected and when I log in in another incognito window, it says 2 visitors. So I feel it's actually working.

Just wondering is the status instanteous? I just want to know whether it's actually working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the tracking code is installed on your website, it will start tracking. So yes, this is instant. Google will only show this instantly in Real Time reporting though and for all the other reports, could take up to 24 hours although is more often, about 3-4 hours.

Google can take a number of days to actually update the tracking status message. There are also known glitches that show this 'Tracking not detected' message for weeks on weeks even though tracking is working perfectly.

If you can see data in GA real time, then it's definitely working and tracking so nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

No the tracking isn't instantaneous. It has gotten faster and faster to come into the reports however Google still states that it can take up to 24 hours for goals etc to register.

Comment: You answered a question that wasn't asked.